How to preserve type information from constructor using generics?
class Registry<Inst, Ctor extends new (...args: unknown[]) => Inst, T extends Readonly<Record<string, Ctor>>> {
  constructor(public records: T) { }
  getCtor<K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
    return this.records[key]
  }
  getInst<K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
    const ctor = this.records[key]
    return new ctor()
  }
}

class Foo { foo: "foo" }
class Bar { bar: "bar" }

const registry = new Registry({
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar
})

const ctor = registry.getCtor('foo') // ctor type is "typeof Foo"
const inst = registry.getInst('foo') // inst type is "unknown", why not "Foo"?

As the comment in last two lines of code says, why the constructor type was preserved, whereas the instance type wasn't?

Edit 1: Simplified code

Generic values will sometimes be widened to their constraints when you do things with them.  If ctor is of generic type C extends new()=>X, then new ctor will become type X instead of staying generic.  The easiest thing to do is use a type assertion as shown here, otherwise you need to refactor your types to make new ctor behave as a single generic operator, as shown here. Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thanks for replying. Yes, both solutions fully address the question. I like the latter solution better since it doesn't rely on type assertions.

The first problem is that you have too many generic type parameters.  The constraint T extends Readonly<Record<string, Ctor>> doesn't serve as an inference site for Ctor, and similarly the constraint Ctor extends new (...args: unknown[]) => Inst doesn't serve as an inference site for Inst. See microsoft/TypeScript#7234, which was eventually declined.  Inference for Ctor and Inst will fail and fall back to the constraints. Your code is therefore equivalent to
class Registry<T extends Readonly<Record<string, new (...args: unknown[]) => unknown>>> {}

and so there's nowhere for Inst to appear in your output, no matter what.
I'd probably change the above to
class Registry<T extends { [K in keyof T]: new () => object }> { }

(there doesn't seem to be much point in Readonly, or allowing arbitrary constructor arguments, or even Record<string, which will end up disallowing interfaces) but it's basically the same.

The problem is that when you have ctor of the generic type T[K], the compiler doesn't understand how to generically interpret new ctor(). You are hoping that it would somehow come up with InstanceType<T[K]>, but InstanceType is a conditional type and the compiler doesn't "get" what it means. Instead, new ctor causes the compiler to widen ctor to its constraint of new () => object and you get just object (or unknown or whatever).
The easiest fix is to just assert that your return type is what you want it to be:
class Registry<T extends { [K in keyof T]: new () => object }> {
    constructor(public records: T) { }
    getCtor<K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
        return this.records[key]
    }
    getInst<K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
        const ctor = this.records[key]
        return new ctor() as InstanceType<T[K]> // assert
    }
}

That works, but requires you to take responsibility for type checking away from the compiler.

A better approach is to make the class generic not in the type of records, but in the corresponding object of instance types. So {foo: Foo, bar: Bar} instead of {foo: typeof Foo, bar: typeof Bar}.  Then we can use a mapped type to express records in terms of T:
class Registry<T extends { [K in keyof T]: object }> {
    constructor(public records: { [K in keyof T]: new () => T[K] }) { }
    getCtor<K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
        return this.records[key]
    }
    getInst<K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
        const ctor = this.records[key]
        return new ctor();
    }
}

Once you do that, then getCtor() returns new () => T[K], and getInst() returns T[K] (because new ctor() applies new to the type new () => T[K], which the compiler does "get".  And that gives you the behavior you want:
class Foo { foo = "foo" }
class Bar { bar = "bar" }

const registry = new Registry({
    foo: Foo,
    bar: Bar
})

const ctor = registry.getCtor('foo') // new () => Foo
const inst = registry.getInst('foo') // Foo

Playground link to code
